# Mean Value Theorem Inequality : Specific question about notation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

First off, this is just my third undergrad math course so I hope what I'm saying makes sense.

My professor showed this MVT Inequality :

∥f(v)−f(w)∥ ≤ sup ∥f '(v+t(w−v))(w−v)∥ for t∈[0,1]
​

I get the idea of what the inequality and what it's saying. The change in the output of f as it moves from v to w cannot be greater than the "maximum" rate in *change* of f as it goes along the line segment from v to w.

My question is with the notation as to why the (w-v) is inside the norm : since it exists to take into account the length of the line segment, shouldn't it be outside the norm? So the inequality should look like :

∥f(v)−f(w)∥ ≤ sup ∥f '(v+t(w−v))∥ *|(w−v)| for t∈[0,1]

So can someone say why the first inequality is "better" than the 2nd one?
​

Comment: I don't quite like your verbalization. When you apply $f'(c)$ to a vector you don't quite get a rate of change (because it is scaled by the length of the vector). Think about the units. At anby rate, if your professor has defined the norm of a linear map (or matrix), then your second version is fine. Note that your class is using $\|v\|$ for the length of $v$, not $|v|$. So you apply the derivative to $w-v$ and then you take the magnitude of that resulting vector. If you know about the norm of a linear map, then it is correct that $\|Ax\| \le \|A\|\|x\|$ (but not equal).

Comment: If this is just at the beginning of your course, and f(x) is a1d function the two inequalities are the same, But why not ask your professor. mabe other students have similar questions and you allwaya have the right to ask.

Comment: The first equation implies the second by cauchy's inequality $\| a \cdot b \| \leq \|a\| \|b\|$. Inequality 1 is based on crude estimation on the fundamental theorem of calculus / MVT, and equality 2 is just a cruder version of inequality 1.